# How to restart rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Sorry it seems like a stupid question, but how do you restart a rails server? I'm following through a Youtube video series and am stuck at the part where it wouldn't let me use the red carpet gem even though I've already installed it.  This is what showed after I typed "Rails server" in the terminal

```
=> Booting Puma 
=> Rails 5.0.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options Exiting /Users/ivychen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined method `action_mailer' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007f8a99846608> (NoMethodError)  
from /Users/ivychen/Code/blog/config/environments/development.rb:30:in `block in <top (required)>'  
from /Users/ivychen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:209:in `instance_eval'  
from /Users/ivychen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:209:in `configure'  
from /Users/ivychen/Code/blog/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'  
from /Users/ivychen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'  
from /Users/ivychen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
```

Can anyone help me what went wrong?

Here's what's in my development.rb file

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.eager_load = false
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true
  if Rails.root.join('tmp/caching-dev.txt').exist?
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.cache_store = :memory_store
  config.public_file_server.headers = {
  'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=172800'
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
config.cache_store = :null_store
  end
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.assets.quiet = true
  config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
end
```

Comment: The key is in the third line where it says, "undefined method `action_mailer'".  Did you recently change something related to that? Also, just so it is clear, the server  and everything is fine, you are restarting it correctly, but there is an error in your code so it is crashing.

Comment: Hmm I don't think I changed anything. What would I need to do to fix the undefined method?

Comment: Can you post development.rb ?  It might be in there, it is kind of hard to know exactly, maybe share a link to the tutorial as well in the post.

Comment: I have a feeling that this question would be a better fit on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) than here.

Comment: @JoeC Not at all — the “Rails Server” is ruby, shipped with Rails, a programming framework, and the errors he's having are runtime errors due to what is likely a typo.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fY2SuLqMD_w&t=827s Here's the video episode..skip to around 11:09.

Comment: Where is your `development.rb`, the typo is most likely there?

Comment: I've copied and pasted the development.rb file in the original post question!!~ –

Comment: @IvyChen Your development.rb looks fine. There's gotta be something else happening in your config/boot process, possibly application.rb, that's either removing your middleware or messing up the `@@options` config hash.

Comment: Ahh weird I still couldn't figure it out! Thanks for taking the time to help though !

Comment: I just restarted the whole project and it works now! :DDD

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to restart the server, since it's raising an exception on boot. You are calling method `action_mailer` on `config/environments/development.rb`, line 30, when it doesn't exist. Resolve that and `rails server` should work again.

Comment: I did that and this came up again, saying that there's an "undefined method 'active-record'. I just went to Sublime and deleted the action_mailer lines in development.rb. Was that what I was supposed to do?

Comment: Ivys-MacBook-Pro:blog ivychen$ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
/Users/ivychen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined method `active_record' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007fea7c475a18> (NoMethodError)
 from /Users/ivychen/Code/blog/config/environments/development.rb:33:in `

Comment: Do I go ahead and delete these 'active_record' lines as well?

Comment: I have no idea what's in your `development.rb` file. You might want to start a separate question to get accurate help.

Comment: I've copied and pasted the development.rb file in the original post question!!~